# Get currently selected cell of QTreeWidget

Tags: python, qtreewidget, pyside2

I'd like to modify `QTreeWidget` to make the selected cell editable when the enter key is hit, but keep the selection to full rows.

I've done a hacky implementation of figuring out where the last click was and saving the value, then sending those values to my `edit_item` function on the key press (also used for the `itemDoubleClicked` signal). It's not great though and I'm wondering if there's a much easier way to do it.

For the record, clicking on an item still selects the whole row. It's probably hidden behaviour by default, but in Maya there's a visible selection thing of the last cell that was moved over while the mouse button was held. If I could somehow get access to that, I could also add in behaviour to control it with the arrow keys.

This is an example of the selected cell:

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
class QTreeWidget(QtWidgets.QTreeWidget):

    returnPressed = QtCore.Signal(QTreeWidget, int)

    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QTreeWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
            self.returnPressed.emit(self._selected_item, self._selected_column)
        else:
            QtWidgets.QTreeWidget.keyPressEvent(self, event)

    def _mouse_pos_calculate(self, x_pos):
        """Find the currently selected column."""
        try:
            item = self.selectedItems()[0]
        except IndexError:
            item = None

        header = self.header()
        total_width = 0
        for i in range(self.columnCount()):
            total_width += header.sectionSize(i)
            if total_width > x_pos:
                return (item, i)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        QtWidgets.QTreeWidget.mousePressEvent(self, event)
        self._selected_item, self._selected_column = self._mouse_pos_calculate(event.pos().x())

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        QtWidgets.QTreeWidget.mouseReleaseEvent(self, event)
        self._selected_item, self._selected_column = self._mouse_pos_calculate(event.pos().x())
```

Edit: Improved function thanks to eyllanesc

```
class QTreeWidget(QtWidgets.QTreeWidget):
    """Add ability to edit cells when pressing return."""
    itemEdit = QtCore.Signal(QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem, int)

    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QTreeWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self._last_item = None
        self._last_column = 0
        self.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self._edit_item_intercept)

    def _edit_item_intercept(self, item=None, column=None):
        if item is None:
            item = self._last_item
        if column is None:
            column = self._last_column
        self.itemEdit.emit(item, column)

    def _store_last_cell(self, pos):
        selected_item = self.itemAt(pos)
        if selected_item is None:
            return
        self._last_item = selected_item
        self._last_column = self.header().logicalIndexAt(pos.x())

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
            return self._edit_item_intercept()
        QtWidgets.QTreeWidget.keyPressEvent(self, event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        QtWidgets.QTreeWidget.mouseMoveEvent(self, event)
        self._store_last_cell(event.pos())
```

Comment: I confused a bit your description of your problem with the code you show, could you explain what your code does?

Comment: by default the QTreeWidget the selection form is for the entire row, so I have a question, if I press enter which of the items in the row should the editing be enabled?

Comment: The "selection" is for the entire row, but as you can see in the image, there's also an individual selection on the cell (it's hard to see with a row selection so I didn't select one for the screenshot). A quick test in Designer shows it's not shown by default, but in the case that Maya has only exposed it, I'm interested in actually getting the information. A bit like if you were to select an excel cell in a way where you can use the arrow keys to move to different ones.

Comment: How do you change that selection? For example, in the image is in the step column, how do you make it in the Timeout column? Do you click on the item with content "210"?

Comment: What do you use returnPressed for?

Comment: If I click on the item with "210", and then click elsewhere in the QTreeWidget to deselect the row, the "210" cell will still be individually selected. If I drag and drop, the individual selection will always be under where the mouse cursor is. `returnPressed` is just for when enter/return is pressed, so I can run it through the same function that I connect `itemDoubleClicked` to.

Comment: okay, from what I understand, a selected row dates, when you click on one of the items that belongs to that row a special selection is generated in the item, and then you want that if you press enter then you should enable the editing of that item with special selection. I am right?

Comment: Yeah basically, the individual selection seems like pretty expected windows behaviour but I can't find any information on it whatsoever. The `i` is just from the loop, I'm manually comparing the mouse x value with the combined header widths to calculate the column.

Comment: Does not that special selection exist at some point?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, but I'm new to Qt and can't find any documentation on it or anything, so I'm a bit stuck. Only a minor issue but it'd be nice to see how you're actually supposed to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a lot of calculation unnecessarily, in the next part I show a cleaner solution:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class QTreeWidget(QtWidgets.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TreeWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.special_item = None
        self.special_col = 0

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
            self.editItem(self.special_item, self.special_col)
        QtWidgets.QTreeWidget.keyPressEvent(self, event)

    def editEnable(self, pos):
        press_item = self.itemAt(pos)
        if press_item is None:
            return
        if press_item is self.selectedItems()[0]:
            col = self.header().logicalIndexAt(pos.x())
            self.special_item = press_item
            self.special_col = col

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        QtWidgets.QTreeWidget.mousePressEvent(self, event)
        self.editEnable(event.pos())
```

Comment: Thanks, I've just set off so will have to try tomorrow morning, assuming there's no way to get the actual selection data, I believe your itemAt line is exactly what I was needing but couldn't find haha

Comment: @Peter 
It would be good if in another answer or in an edition of your question you indicate couple of tweaks. :)

Comment: Haha, by a few tweaks it was literally only a few minor things specific to my case. For example I don't want to directly call `editItem` as I have a wrapper that lets you disable columns, and I changed `mousePressEvent` to `mouseMoveEvent` to also work as expected when dragging. Finally I just sent `itemDoubleClicked` to the same function I call when hitting enter, so that they both send an `itemEdit` signal :)  I'll add a bit on to the end of the question though